# using linq to sql to find common data

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq to sql to pull data from my IQueryable object in my mvc project. In this case, I am trying to find albums that users have in common. Thanks for any help.

```
Albums.Where(x=>x.userid == _userid && x.userid == _otheruserid);
//This will pull all the respected albums from each user. 
//I just would like to pull the albums they have in common
```

Comment: Does an Album have a unique identifier?  Normally you would use three tables for this:  a User table, an Album table, and a User_Albums table which links the other two.

Comment: Does the code you have in your question run as expected? `Albums.Where(x=>x.userid == _userid && x.userid == _otheruserid)` will only retrieve albums when `_userid == _otheruserid` - which would imply the same user.

Comment: I think the query that you provided is incorrect, it should be || instead of &&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx). Pretty easy:

```
Albums.Where(x=>x.userid ==_userid) 
.Intersect(Albums.Where(x=>x.userid== _otheruserid));
```

Edit:
For the code you've provided, you want to use a specific field to match on, since you cannot have one Album with two different Users assigned to it. if you want to find albums that are common based on the name, you can try to use this:

```
 Albums.Where(x=>x.userid ==_userid).Select(x=>x.Name) 
    .Intersect(Albums.Where(x=>x.userid== _otheruserid).Select(x=>x.Name));
```

but as @EvilPenguin mentioned, you're probably better off creating a better structure for your tables.

Comment: Given the code, I assume in the model that if User1 and User2 both have the same Album, the two Albums will be different objects as Album has userid

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin, Yes, you're probably right. Probably OP wants to find them based on a specific property. let me update my answer.